# Prevent repeating special character and by specific count using RegEx For Email

Tags: regex, validation, string-matching, regex-group, regex-negation

How can I use RegEx to test for the following pattern:

1. String length doesn't matter.
2. The special character sign (-) should not be repeated **consecutively**.
3. The special character sign (-) should not occur more than **twice** in the entire string and (.) sign not to be present more than two times before mail's domain

**Sample Cases:**

Match:

```
Jessica-Parker@gmail.com
Jessica-Parker@gmail.com
Jessica-Parker-Smith@gmail.com
Jessica.Parker-Smith@gmail.com
Jessica.Parker.Smith@gmail.com
```

Unmatch:

```
Jessica--Parker@gmail.com
Jeff--smith-Parker@gmail.com
Jessica-Parker--@gmail.com
Jessica-Parker-@gmail.com
Jessica.P.Jane.Smith@gmail.com
Jessica..P.Jane.Smith@gmail.com
```

Struggling with third part,I figured out the First two part as:

```
^(?!.*(-)\1{2})(\w[\w\.-]*@[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)\b
```

Comment: Please provide examples of what you mean.  Thanks

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/982mCF/1, please add the examples that do not work for you to this regex fiddle and share.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Have updated the Query. Thank you, will give it a shot!

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^(?![^@]*([-.])\1)(?![^@]*([-.])(?:[^@]*\2){2})\w(?:[\w.-]*\w)?@(?:[a-zA-Z]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/982mCF/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![^@]*([-.])\1)` -  no double hyphen/dot anywhere after 0 or more chars other than `@` are allowed
- `(?![^@]*([-.])(?:[^@]*\2){2})` - no 3 or more `-`/`.` chars after any 0 or more chars other than `@` are allowed
- `\w` - a word char
- `(?:[\w.-]*\w)?` - an optional sequence of 0 or more word, `.` or `-` chars followed with a word char
- `@` -  a `@` char
- `(?:[a-zA-Z]+\.)+` - 1 or more occurrences of 1+ letters followed with a dot
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @Jason You should have posted the full regex and explain the real requirements. This seems quite a different question, try [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/76CymT/2).

Comment: Apologies , my requirement is for email. I am able to allow one special character but not twice. I wanna restrict it on third time

Comment: @Jason So use the technique as shown in https://regex101.com/r/76CymT/2

Comment: not working as expected. only one - special character is accepted. I need two to be accepted

Comment: @Jason Then ask the right question. Your current question is answered.

Comment: Wiktor, the solution you pointed is not matching consecutive case.

Comment: @Jason `(?!.*-{2})` answers it. No two consecutive hyphens. **Update the question with real life examples and real life pattern / requirements** if you need a more precise answer.